# How to edit the axis values manually while plotting insets in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, insets

I want to edit the axis values while plotting a graph with insets in matplotlib. I know how to do it when it's a regular plot but I can't seem to figure this out. I have attached a graph with inset below.
[image]

Here, I want to change the values 0.0 and 1.0 on the x-axis to 0 and 1. In the y-axis, I want to change 1.0 and 2.0 to just 1 and 2. I want to do a similar thing to the inset graph too. I hope my question is clear and I am looking forward to your response.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit, e.g. the x axis ticklabels by `ax.set_xticklabels()`. As mentioned in the [corresponding docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) you also should use `ax.set_xticks()` to fix the tick positions.

For both axes:

```
# Assuming that ax is the plot's axis
ax.set_xticks(range(3))
ax.set_xticklabels((0, 0.5, 1))

ax.set_yticks(range(6))
ax.set_yticklabels((1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2))
```